# Put files in android emulator on linux

Tags: android, continuous-integration, android-emulator, ui-testing

I would like to put media files in the emulator when creating or before starting the emulator.
Please tell me how you can implement this?

Comment: You want to transfer files from your computer to Android Studio emulator ?

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI no, emulator on linux server. 
there are files in my folder that I want to put in the emulator